# Is there a way to get Durbin Watson critical values in R?

Tags: r

I'm talking about this table:

[image]

Is there a way I can find these values without looking at the table?

Something like `dw_critical(n=1, k=2, lower=TRUE, alpha=0.05)`

I know you can find z-values and t-values this way in R.

Comment: Unfortunately, you may not be able to do such a static table since D-W statistic depends on the model structure and [residuals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durbin%E2%80%93Watson_statistic). See [R: Calculate p-value given Durbin Watson statistic and n](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/136664). This screenshot may be used for approximation given a *n* and *k*.

Comment: What if you're just given a list/vector of residuals, how do you calculate the D-W static in R without calculating the formula manually?